# Power Automate - how to pass rich text from SharePoint to Word?

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, word-template

I'm trying to send text from a multiline SharePoint column to a Word doc, using Power Automate. The html_to_text action recognises a bulleted list (which I don't need), but it doesn't seem to recognise words in bold, which I do need.

Any ideas how to pass the bold formatting?

Answer (score 0):

Currently we cannot pass the bold formatting.

This is by design that **Bold** will not be retained, and [Unordered lists will use * as prefix](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/conversionservice/#element-specific-behavior-of-content-conversion-service) when we use Content Conversion service:

[image][image]

More information about Html to text action for your reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/conversionservice/#html-to-text

Comment: Thanks @Julie_MSFT. Is there any way to pass bold formatting over? With a Compose perhaps? Or in an html table?

Comment: Short answer is no.Compose and html table is not suitable for this issue.